# Saving refreshed power query excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, win32com, xlwings

I have an excel file called refresh_excel.xlsx where a simple power query written to get files in a folder and combine and load them and to see the records.For the automation purposes I have a simple python script as below.

```
import win32com.client
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open('D:/Others/refresh_excel.xlsx')

xlapp.Visible = True # This is only for the debugging purposes
wb.RefreshAll()
xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()


wb.Save() ## Python hangs 
xlapp.Quit()
```

At the save step my python hangs and when I see the excel frontend using `xlapp.Visible` I can see  that a separate window opened to make as save as.

I just need to overwrite the excel file 'refresh_excel.xlsx' using python after the refresh is done.

Comment: If a SaveAs box is appearing, Excel must be having an issue saving the original file. Maybe try opening the file manually in Excel and hitting Save, and see if there are any clues as to the problem (file permissions, format etc). As a quick test of the Python, see if you can open the file and save it: ie do not try and refresh the queries. Maybe also try writing the same script as a VBA macro. Also check the settings on the query, and turn off 'background queries', and see it that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a call to wb.Close().
You're quitting Excel without closing the file. The MS UI handles this and prompts to save ect.

But you are orphaning a file in memory from the app it was opened with when you close the app without closing the file.

You can replace wb.Save() with wb.Close(TRUE) before your xlapp.Quit() statement.